react-query result is useQueryResult<unknown, unknown>
I am use react-query version 4 and having issues with TypeScript types flowing through.
I have this async fetch:
interface FetchResult<TResult> {
  body?: TResult;
  error? string;
}

function get<TResult>(params): Promise<FetchResult<TResult>> {
// processes the result into FetchResult
}

function getTodos() {
  return get<Todo[]>({ url: "/api/todos" });
}

I have this consuming hook:
function useTodos() {
  return useQuery({
    queryKey: ["todos"],
    queryFn: async () => {
      const {error, body} = await getTodos();
      if(Boolean(error)) {
        throw new Error(error);
      }
      return body; // type in intellisense = Todo[]
    }

}

Finally, in my component I use the hook:
const {data, error, isFetching} = useTodos(); // data type = unknown, error type = unknown

Why isn't data's type Todos[] | undefined? Why doesn't the type flow through?
